# Update a dbf file with datagridview in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, dataset, dbf

Recently my mentor asked me to write a program,manipulating the dbf file in C#.I'm using Odbc & OleDb and now I can read the dbf to datagridview with a dataset.

My question is : *how can I input some data in datagridview after reading from the local dbf file and update my input to the local dbf file?*

I am new to this, not familiar with relevent APIs so example codes would be a great help.
Here is my code to read the dbf file to datagridvie

```
string filePath = @"C:\Users\csj\Desktop\db\ZMT.dbf";   
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filePath);
string mulu = fi.DirectoryName;
string filename = fi.Name;

OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
string table = filePath;

string connStr = @"Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=" + mulu + ";Collating   Sequence=MACHINE";

conn.ConnectionString = connStr;
conn.Open();

string sql = @"select * from " + filename;
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conn);
DataSet dt = new DataSet();
da.Fill(dt);
conn.Close(); conn.Dispose(); 
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a OleDbCommandBuilder after you created your OleDbDataAdapter

```
var builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(da);
```

The builder creates Update, Insert and Delete commands for the OleDbDataAdapter.

Then after you made changes in the grid you simply call

```
da.Update(dt);
```

That's how it should work ... but I didn't try this for dbfs ...